# Почему половина символов, которые я получаю из Яндекс.Переводчика, отдаются в непонятном виде?

Tags: php, яндекс-переводчик

Собственно есть сайт, который работает через yandex translate api. Суть в чем, скрипт в реальном времени парсит информацию переводит ее и вывод на страницах сайта уже на нужном языке.

До позавчера все было нормально, работал почти год. Но в друг, половина символов, толком и ненят сначала, начала отдаваться в непонятном виде, что-то похожее на json.

Приведу пример:

PHP код:

```
include_once 'Yandex_Translate.php';  
include_once 'Big_Text_Translate.php'; 

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=win-1251');  
      
    function GTR($str,$in1,$in2) {  
    $translator = new Yandex_Translate();  
    $bigText = $str;  
    $textArray = Big_Text_Translate::toBigPieces($bigText);  
    $numberOfTextItems = count($textArray);  
    foreach ($textArray as $key=>$textItem){  
        $translatedItem = $translator->yandexTranslate($in1, $in2, $textItem);  
        $translatedArray***91;$key***93; = $translatedItem;  
    }  
    $translatedBigText = Big_Text_Translate::fromBigPieces($translatedArray);  
    return $translatedBigText;  
    }  


$category1='<a href="/recept/season/leto/">Лето</a>, <a href="/recept/season/osen/">Осень</a>'; //получил текст (в реальном скрипте парсится по регулярке)

$category1=iconv('windows-1251','utf-8//IGNORE',$category1);  //сменил кодировку
$category1=GTR($category1,'ru','uk'); //перевел
$category1=iconv('utf-8','windows-1251//IGNORE',$category1); //вернул кодировку
$category1=str_replace('\"','"',$category1); //удалил екранирование кавычек

echo $category1; //вывел
```

В итоге получаю вот такое:

> \ta hreff="recepttseasonnletoo/"Літоо \ta hreff="recepttseasonnosenn/"Осіньь<aa \tnbspp

Файл в кодировке win-1251, источник парсинга в UTF-8, яндекс API работает с UTF.

Попробовал в другом скрипте, создал новый файл, залил в него код

PHP код:

```
include_once 'Yandex_Translate.php';  
include_once 'Big_Text_Translate.php'; 

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=win-1251');  
      
    function GTR($str,$in1,$in2) {  
    $translator = new Yandex_Translate();  
    $bigText = $str;  
    $textArray = Big_Text_Translate::toBigPieces($bigText);  
    $numberOfTextItems = count($textArray);  
    foreach ($textArray as $key=>$textItem){  
        $translatedItem = $translator->yandexTranslate($in1, $in2, $textItem);  
        $translatedArray***91;$key***93; = $translatedItem;  
    }  
    $translatedBigText = Big_Text_Translate::fromBigPieces($translatedArray);  
    return $translatedBigText;  
    }  

$q='<li ><a href="/sait">Переводчик</a></li>';
$q=iconv('windows-1251','utf-8//IGNORE',$q);
$q=iconv('utf-8','windows-1251//IGNORE',$q);
echo $q;
```

Выводит нормальную ссылку....

Где проблема в первом варианте ума не приложу... Может кто-то из гуру подскажет?

P.S: пробовал после каждой строки делать вывод, чтобы увидеть на каком этапе проблема, проблема появляется после строки:

```
$category1=GTR($category1,'ru','uk'); //перевел
```

Для перевода использую вот [этот код](http://code.google.com/p/translate-api/source/browse/trunk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API яндекс переводчика поменялось. Теперь запросы отравляются на https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json (для json) и https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr/ (для xml) + нужно получить ключ API переводчика